# How to nest a d3.arc inside another?

Tags: d3.js, geometry

I'm attempting to nest an arc generated using `d3.arc` perfectly inside another arc.

I can do this by drawing "on my own":

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script data-require="d3@4.0.0" data-semver="4.0.0" src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <script>
    function arc_position(x, y, radius, angle) {
      return {
        x: x + (radius * Math.cos(angle)),
        y: y + (radius * Math.sin(angle))
      };
    }

    function describe_arc(x, y, radius, startAngle, endAngle) {

      var s = arc_position(x, y, radius, endAngle);
      var e = arc_position(x, y, radius, startAngle);

      var sweep = e - s <= 180 ? '0' : '1';

      var d = [
        'M', s.x, s.y,
        'A', radius, radius, 0, sweep, 0, e.x, e.y
      ].join(' ');

      return d;
    }

    var svg = d3.select("body")
      .append("svg")
      .attr("width", 500)
      .attr("height", 500)
      .append("g");
      
    var s = arc_position(250, 250, 200, Math.PI/2);
    var e = arc_position(250, 250, 200, (Math.PI * 3)/2);
      
    svg.append("path")
      .style("fill", "none")
      .style("stroke", "orange")
      .style("stroke-width", "20px")
      .attr("d", describe_arc(250,250,180,(Math.PI * 3)/2, Math.PI/2));
      
    svg.append("path")
      .style("fill", "none")
      .style("stroke", "orange")
      .style("stroke-width", "20px")
      .attr("d", "M" + (s.x + 30) + "," + s.y + "L" + (e.x + 30) + "," + e.y);

    svg.append("path")
      .style("fill", "none")
      .style("stroke", "steelblue")
      .style("stroke-width", "20px")
      .attr("d", describe_arc(250,250,200,(Math.PI * 3)/2, Math.PI/2));
    
    svg.append("path")
      .style("fill", "none")
      .style("stroke", "steelblue")
      .style("stroke-width", "20px")
      .attr("d", "M" + (s.x + 10) + "," + s.y + "L" + (e.x + 10) + "," + e.y);
    
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

But I can't figure out a methodology using `d3.arc`:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <script data-require="d3@4.0.0" data-semver="4.0.0" src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <script>
      
      var svg = d3.select("body")
        .append("svg")
        .attr("width", 500)
        .attr("height", 500)
        .append("g")
        .attr("transform","translate(250,250)");
        
      var arc = d3.arc()
        .innerRadius(0)
        .outerRadius(200)
        .startAngle(0)
        .endAngle(Math.PI);

      svg.append("path")
        .style("fill", "none")
        .style("stroke", "steelblue")
        .style("stroke-width", "20px")
        .attr("d", arc());
        
      arc.outerRadius(200 - 40);
      
      svg.append("path")
        .style("fill", "none")
        .style("stroke", "orange")
        .style("stroke-width", "20px")
        .attr("d", arc())
        .attr("transform", "translate(20,0)")
      
    </script>
  </body>

</html>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: @gerardofurtado, any ideas?

Comment: Mate, I'm flattered, but compared to you I'm still a learner!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think that there is a good way to do this just using `d3.arc` because that is meant for drawing sections of circles and you're trying to draw a partial ellipse.

You can get close by generating the angle offset using the stroke width and the radius of the inner arc as `offsetAngle = sin(stroke width / inner radius)`. The arc's `startAngle` is the `offsetAngle` and the `endAngle` is `Math.PI - offsetAngle`.

Unfortunately, that will generate a path which includes the center point of the circle. You can hack together something that works by just removing the `L0,0` from the generated path (`innerArc().replace("L0,0","")`) and this will give you what you want, albeit in an ugly fashion.

Because it is a fairly simple path, it is probably best to use your own path generator to do this instead.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <script data-require="d3@4.0.0" data-semver="4.0.0" src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <script>
      
      var svg = d3.select("body")
        .append("svg")
        .attr("width", 500)
        .attr("height", 500)
        .append("g")
        .attr("transform","translate(250,250)");
        
      var outerRadius = 200;
      var stroke = 20;
      var innerRadius = outerRadius - stroke;
      var innerAngle = Math.sin(stroke/innerRadius);

      var outerArc = d3.arc()
        .innerRadius(0)
        .outerRadius(outerRadius)
        .startAngle(0)
        .endAngle(Math.PI);

      var innerArc = d3.arc()
        .innerRadius(0)
        .outerRadius(innerRadius)
        .startAngle(innerAngle)
        .endAngle(Math.PI - innerAngle);

      svg.append("path")
        .style("fill", "none")
        .style("stroke", "steelblue")
        .style("stroke-width", stroke)
        .attr("d", outerArc());
      
      svg.append("path")
        .style("fill", "none")
        .style("stroke", "orange")
        .style("stroke-width", stroke)
        .attr("d", innerArc().replace("L0,0",""));
      
    </script>
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: Upvoted, I believe that this is the correct explanation.

Answer (score 3):

*(This is not an answer, but just a comment, which I chose to disguise as an answer because I need the S.O. snippet)*

I believe that [Paul S](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41082900/5768908) is right, and he deserves the *big prize* of the green tick: what you're trying to paint in the inner (orange) path is **not** an arc of a circumference, but an *ellipse* instead. And, as the docs say,

> The arc generator produces a circular or annular sector

, which will not work for creating an elliptic sector.

You can easily see that in the following demo: using a for loop, we draw arcs with decreasing outer radius. The only way to perfectly fill the internal space of each arc is if the next, smaller arch has **the same center** of the precedent, bigger one:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <script data-require="d3@4.0.0" data-semver="4.0.0" src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <script>
      
      var svg = d3.select("body")
        .append("svg")
        .attr("width", 500)
        .attr("height", 500)
        .append("g")
        .attr("transform","translate(250,250)");
        
      var arc = d3.arc()
        .innerRadius(0)
        .outerRadius(200)
        .startAngle(0)
        .endAngle(Math.PI);
      
      var color = d3.scaleOrdinal(d3.schemeCategory10);
      
      for(var i = 0; i<11; i++){

      svg.append("path")
        .style("stroke", color(i))
        .style("fill", "none")
        .style("stroke-width", "20px")
        .attr("d", arc());
        
      arc.outerRadius(200 - 20*i);
        
        };
      
    </script>
  </body>

</html>
```

There is an even easier way to visualize that. Let's create a single arc, with a huge stroke:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <script data-require="d3@4.0.0" data-semver="4.0.0" src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <script>
      
      var svg = d3.select("body")
        .append("svg")
        .attr("width", 500)
        .attr("height", 500)
        .append("g")
        .attr("transform","translate(250,250)");
        
      var arc = d3.arc()
        .innerRadius(0)
        .outerRadius(150)
        .startAngle(0)
        .endAngle(Math.PI);

      svg.append("path")
        .style("fill", "none")
        .style("stroke", "steelblue")
        .style("stroke-width", "100px")
        .attr("d", arc());
        
      
    </script>
  </body>

</html>
```

Look at the blue arc: it is a semicircle. Now look at the white space inside it: it's clearly **not** a semicircle. The blue thing is a semicircle, but the space inside it is not.

So, as `d3.arc()` right now doesn't have the option to set **two different focal points**, the options are creating your own function (as you did) or hacking the path (as Paul S did).

Answer (score 0):

You draw second arc with outer radius `R - 2 * strokewidth` and center shifted by `strokewidth`.

But smaller arc should have **the same center** as larger one and outer radius `R - strokewidth`